# Exclude documents based on multiple criteria

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection has the following schema:

```
{
_id:1,
eventname:"Add to Cart",
userId:1,
attributes:{amount:1000,item:"shirt"}
},
{
_id:2,
 eventname:"Add to Cart",
userId:1,
attributes:{amount:1000,item:"shoes"}
},
{
_id:3,
eventname:"Item Viewed",
userId:2,
attribtes:{product:"laptop",size:"14-in"}
},
{
_id:4,
 eventname:"Item Viewed",
 userId:2,
     attribtes:{product:"laptop",size:"15-in"}
 },
 {
 _id:5,
  eventname:"Add to Cart",
  userId:2,
  attribtes:{amount:"1500",item:"trouser"}
  }
```

return userId list who did not perform

eventname Item Viewed and product is laptop whose size is 15-inch.

Expected output: all documents except with `_id = 4`